# How to remove a special tag with regex

Tags: javascript

I have such string:

```
<![if !]>1.  <![]>Interpretation

<![if !]>1.1   <![]>Defined Terms: In this Agreement:
```

I need:

```
1.Interpretation

1.1 Defined Terms: In this Agreement:
```

Comment: And so far you've tried the `.replace()` method, or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
'<![if !]>1.  <![]>Interpretation'.replace(/(<\!\[if \!\]>|<\!\[\]\>)/g,'')
```

Hope this help.